# Function that convert int to array of char, some questions

Tags: c, arrays, null, char

This code need to get an int number and convert it to array of char that present the number:
for example :

The number 324

convert to this:
like:

```
char newstr [6] = {'3','2','4','\0','\0','\0'};
```

1. I think that '\0' is null, right?

What is wrong with my code ?

also how can I change this to a function that get an int number and return array of char that present it?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main ()
 {
   int value = 324;
   char str [6];
   char newstr [6];
   int pointer, i = 0;

   for(i=0; value>0; i++)
     {
        str[i] = value%10 + '0';
        value /=10;
     }

        str[i] = '\0';

   for(i=5; i>-1; i--)
     {
       if(str[i]!='\0')
        {
         newstr[pointer] = str[i];
         pointer++;  
        }
     }

   for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
     {
        printf("%d  %c\n", i, newstr[i] );
     }
    printf ("shalom");
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way should be calling `sprintf()`.

```
char newstr[6] = {0};
sprintf(newstr, "%d", value);
```

In your existing code, `str` looks lile `{'4', '2', '3', '\0', SomethingRandom, SomethingRandom}`. Reversing it and assign to `newstr` makes it `{SomethingRandom, SomethingRandom, '\0', '3', '2', '4'}`, which is definitely not what you want. And indeed you don't assign `newstr` when `str[i] == '\0'`, which means `newstr[2] == SomethingRandom`.

Comment: I need it to convert to ary of char. so sprintf() dosen't help me.
I can use an for() that will complete my array with "nulls".
what is wrong with : if(str[i]!='\0')?

Comment: @ShayShtern `char newstr[6] = {0};` initializes the whole `newstr` with `'\0'`, and `sprintf()` fills the non-`'\0'` bytes.

Comment: @ShayShtern: `sprintf()` fills an array of `char` exactly as specified by your question.

Comment: @alk `sprintf()` would not fill an array per OP's specifications.  It will not fill extra `'\0'`.  Of course the array could be filled with `'\0'` beforehand and then `sprintf()` called.  As long as there is not buffer overrun, all is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * itoa( int x )
{
    const unsigned int BASE = 10;
    unsigned int u = abs( x );
    size_t n = 0;
    unsigned int tmp = u;
    char *s;

    do { ++n; } while ( tmp /= BASE );

    n += x < 0;

    s = malloc( ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( char ) );

    s[n] = '\0';

    do
    {
        s[--n] = u % BASE + '0';
    } while ( u /= BASE );

    if ( x < 0 ) s[--n] = '-';

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *s = itoa( -1234567890 );

    printf( "%s\n", s );

    free( s );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
-1234567890
```

As for your question what is wrong with your code then it is entirely wrong.:) 
For example the code ignores numbers that are equal to zero. Variable pointer was not initialized

```
int pointer, i = 0;
```

each loop deals with some garbage and so on.

It will be more helpful for you if you will investigate my code.

Comment: I am just beginner so I'm not that good yet..!
Thanks alot i will look at that!!
I'm  here to learn!! keep replying and help people!!
have a good day !

Comment: @Shay Shtern  I am just an unemployed. So I am not so bad yet as others who has a job.:).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow LoL! :)

Answer (score 1):

OP's code looks very close to being correct for limited usage.

Do not start with `value>0` test, otherwise when `value == 0`, the result will be `""`.  Be sure to limit the number of iterations to not exceed the array size.

```
do {
  str[i] = value%10 + '0';
  value /=10;
  i++;
} while (value>0 && i < (6-1));
```

Set `'\0'` in a loop.  [@timra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27678199/2410359) points out random unset elements.

```
do {
  str[i] = '\0';
  i++;
} while (i < (6-1));
```

OP still has 2 remaining issues which OP has yet to specify what to do:

> Values greater than 99999
>   Values < 0

BTW: "I think that '\0' is null, right?"  `'\0'` is the "null character".  This differs from `NULL`, the "null pointer".

---

"how can I change this to a function that get an int number and return array of char that present it"

OP's code has a number of corner problems.  Suggest a new approach.
Perform conversion into local array and then return a copy of it.
Calling code should eventually `free()` it.

```
#include <limits.h>

// max size needed for int.  Note 10/33 just greater than log(2)
#define INTSIZE_MAX (sizeof int * CHAR_BIT * 10 / 33 + 3)

char *intoa_alloc(int x) {
  char buf[INTSIZE_MAX];
  char *p = &buf[sizeof buf - 1];

  // Work with negative absolute value to cope with INT_MIN
  // This avoids portability problems with abs(x) approach.
  int x_negative = x < 0 ? x : -x;

  // Form string
  *p = '\0';
  do {
    *--p = '0' - x_negative % 10;
    x_negative /= 10;
  } while (x_negative);
  if (x < 0) {
    *--p = '-';
  }

  char *dest = malloc(strlen(p) + 1);
  if (dest) {
    strcpy(dest, p);
  }
  return dest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this simple way you can do that.

```
int main()
{
char str [6] = "324";
printf ("%c",str[1]);
  return 0;
}
```